# Open CSV files from a directory with IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am trying to open with a for loop 25 csv file one after the other in IDL

I have the following code:-

```
The_file_list=FILE_SEARCH('D:/MapsCharts/PairedStations/','*.csv',/FOLD_CASE)

 FOR Filein =  0, N_ElEMENTS (The_file_list)-1 DO BEGIN 
 Print, Filein
 OPENR,1,filein
 temp=''
 READF,1,temp
 Station=STRMID(temp,1,13)

 ENDFOR
```

The first line works but I cannot get the individual file data

Can somebody advise

Answer (score 0):

In you code `Filein` is an integer from `0` to `N_ELEMENTS(the_file_list) - 1`, not a file. So when you do:

```
openr, 1, filein
```

that is trying to open a file named `0`, `1`, etc. You mean:

```
openr, 1, the_file_list[filein]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is as follows

```
The_NETCDF_File=FILE_SEARCH('D:/Rwork/The28000files/*')

The_NETCDF_CODE=STRMID(The_NETCDF_File,23,14)

; This is the CSV file containing the 25 neighbouring stations to$
; canadiate(pilot) stations
```

The_file_list=FILE_SEARCH('D:/MapsCharts/PairedStations/','*.csv',/FOLD_CASE)

FOR Filein =  0, N_ElEMENTS (The_file_list)-1 DO BEGIN

Current_file=the_file_list[filein]

My_File_Names = READ_CSV(Current_File)

; Pulling out only the station ID without the extension of the csv files
   Station_Names=My_File_Names.field1